# Add connected service only adding reference.cs VS 2019 ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to add a webservice to a console application I'm writing.

Server side: There is no problem and I managed to create the .asmx as normal.

Client side: Here whenever I look at tutorials and videos they just add the connected service and already can use commands like: `"localhost.Service1 myMathService = new localhost.Service1();`"  but in my case I add it as connected service (and got a few more menus to go through than the tutorials state) and then I got:

Connected Services  (name is updatelogger)

- FOLDER:  updatelogger

and in that folder there is connectedservice.json and reference.cs.

Thus using it like here: `"localhost.Service1 myMathService = new localhost.Service1();`" is impossible for me as there is "only" an asynchron task instead of a direct reference to the web method.

As the tutorials and help pages don't state anything there the question for me is: Where did I go down the wrong path?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76610836/how-to-consume-local-asmx-web-service-from-net-console-application.
would this post help?

Comment: @woodykiddy yes that looks exactly like what I need thanks (didn't show up on my searches). Is there anything known why its now THAT complicated? (even the microsoft help pages only show the old simpler method to consume the webservices and not this a bit more complicated one)